# Как подключить библиотеку assimp статически?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, компоновщик

Я использовал данный [урок](https://ravesli.com/urok-16-biblioteka-importa-3d-modelej-assimp-v-opengl/)
для подключения библиотеки assimp к visual studio 2019 (только с конфигурацией Win32), но мне нужно подключить библиотеку статически, без .dll файлов. Я плохо разбираюсь в использовании CMake, поэтому не знаю как это реализовать.

Assimp версия 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам как минимум нужно собрать эту библиотеку статически. Для этого выставте опцию `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` в `OFF`. После этого все как обычно: указываете в `target_link_libraries` эту цель и она будет слинкована статически